# Jira groovy script error

Tags: groovy, jira

I'm getting groovy records from SQL Table or Function. Example;

```
String subeKodu = get_sube_kodu_bul(matcher[0][1])

private String get_sube_kodu_bul(String subeAdi) {
   def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.xx.xx.xx:1433/DBNAME", "usrname","pass", "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver")
   subeAdi = subeAdi.trim()
   def row = sql.firstRow("SELECT TOP 1 SUBE_KODU FROM TABLENAME WHERE SUBE_ADI= '${subeAdi}'")
   row != null ? (String)row.SUBE_KODU : ''
}
```

But  I am faced with the following error;

```
WARNING: In Groovy SQL please do not use quotes around dynamic expressions (which start with $) as this means we cannot use a JDBC PreparedStatement and so is a security hole. Groovy has worked around your mistake but the security hole is still there. The expression so far is: SELECT TOP 1 YETKILI FROM TABLENAME WHERE SUBE_ADI = '?'
```

Comment: Shouldn't it just be: `"SELECT TOP 1 SUBE_KODU FROM TABLENAME WHERE SUBE_ADI= $subeAdi"`?

Comment: Hi Opal, the same error

Answer (score 5):

Groovy is complaining that your code may be vulnerable to a [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

The proper way to do this is with [JDBC Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). In Groovy, you do this as follows:

```
sql.firstRow("SELECT TOP 1 SUBE_KODU FROM TABLENAME WHERE SUBE_ADI= ?", [subeAdi])
```

For more examples of this, see [the Groovy SQL tutorial](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+6+-+Groovy+SQL) and search for "prepared statements".

Also, don't forget to call close() when you are done.

Comment: @Sinanysl: I believe Scott meant it with quotes around question mark: `sql.firstRow("SELECT TOP 1 SUBE_KODU FROM TABLENAME WHERE SUBE_ADI= '?'", [subeAdi])`